# Python: Is it possible to upload images to Firebase Storage using an image URL and not the image file?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to use Python, the Reddit API, and Firebase to store images from reddit in Firebase Storage and then put the URL from firebase storage in a doc.

Right now I am just storing the URL that the reddit api provides in my project's Firebase Database. BUT this is a problem since sometimes these URLs "go bad and expire" meaning that when I grab a doc and display the URL I have stored I get an error.

This is how I am getting the information before creating the doc in firebase

```
function getJSON(sub){
    var ret;

    var yourUrl="https://www.reddit.com/r/"+sub+".json";

    fetch(yourUrl).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(data){
        var i = 5;
        list= data.data.children
            curlist = list[i].data
            if(curlist.domain==='i.redd.it'){
                if(curlist.post_hint==='image'){
                    var url =curlist.url;
                    var author=curlist.author;
                    var time=curlist.created_utc;
                    var score = curlist.score;
                    sendToFirebase(url,author,sub,time,score);
            }

            }
    }).catch(err => {
    });
}
```

What I would like to do instead of putting the reddit URL in the doc is take this reddit URL and store the image that is at the end of this URL in my Firebase Storage, so that way I can take the image URL that is stored in Firebase Storage and put it in the doc.

Comment: You will have to download the file from the URL locally, then upload it to Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDKs require that the image data is available on the local client to be able to upload it to Cloud Storage. There are no methods that take an external image URL of the data to upload to Cloud Storage.

If the image is not local to the client, you will first need to download it to the client, before uploading it to Cloud Storage with the Firebase SDK.